# What is proper way to remove python tests from SonarQube analysis

Tags: python, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to get tests excluded from SonarQube analysis.
i have set following in sonarscanner in Jenkins:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=manage.py, rone/wsgi.py, rone/settings/**, rone/utils/**, rone/service/tests/**
```

and i have coverage and xunit report included.

```
sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=./rone_env/rone_service/coverage.xml
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=./rone_env/rone_service/xunittest.xml
```

Problem with this is that i don't get xunittest results analyzed as it doesn't find test files to get detailed info.

So i have added following to include test files for xunittest result.

```
sonar.tests=./rone/service/tests
```

Now i get xunittest nicely reported but i get also tests analyzed to Code Smells and Duplications which i don't want.

I have tried different combinatios of using exclusions and inclusions

```
sonar.test.inclusions
sonar.test.exclusions
sonar.coverage.exclusions
sonar.cpd.exclusions
```

with no luck.

SonarQube release is Version 6.7.6

SonarScanner release is 3.3.0.1492

**EDIT 1.**

Here is full SonarScanner config. tests folder has 13 test files which all are included in code analysis.

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=RoneService

# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=rone_service
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set.
sonar.sources=.
sonar.tests=./rone/service/tests
sonar.exclusions=manage.py, rone/wsgi.py, rone/settings/**, rone/utils/**, rone/service/tests/**

sonar.language=py
sonar.projectBaseDir=./rone_env/rone_service

# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
# sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Python Coverage Results Import
sonar.python.coverage.reportPaths=./rone_env/rone_service/coverage.xml

# Python Unit Tests Execution Reports Import
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=./rone_env/rone_service/xunittest.xml

# Import Pylint Issues Report
sonar.python.pylint.reportPath=./rone_env/rone_service/pylint-report.txt 

# Add this line to Additional arguments field to get more verbose debug logs from SonarScanner
# -Dsonar.verbose=true -X
```

**EDIT 2.**

here is debug logs from indexing files

```
10:41:19.397 INFO: Language is forced to py
10:41:19.402 DEBUG: Initializers : 
10:41:19.403 INFO: Index files
10:41:19.406 INFO: Excluded sources: 
10:41:19.406 INFO:   manage.py
10:41:19.406 INFO:   rone/wsgi.py
10:41:19.406 INFO:   rone/settings/**
10:41:19.406 INFO:   rone/utils/**
10:41:19.406 INFO:   rone/service/tests/**
10:41:19.423 DEBUG: 'rone/__init__.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.428 DEBUG: 'rone/service/__init__.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.429 DEBUG: 'rone/service/models.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.431 DEBUG: 'rone/service/urls.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.432 DEBUG: 'rone/service/serializers/keytask.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.433 DEBUG: 'rone/service/serializers/rulegroup.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.433 DEBUG: 'rone/service/views/__init__.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.435 DEBUG: 'rone/service/views/keytask.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.436 DEBUG: 'rone/service/views/rulegroup.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.437 DEBUG: 'rone/service/apps.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.440 DEBUG: 'rone/urls.py' indexed with language 'py'
10:41:19.446 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_rulegroup_create.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.446 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/__init__.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.448 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_rulegroup_filerules_update.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.449 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_applicationfilerule_create.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.450 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_rulegroup_delete.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.451 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_keytask.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.451 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_rulegroup_list.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.452 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_applicationfilerule_list.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.453 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_rulegroup_filerules_update_property.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.455 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/local_test_mixin.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.456 DEBUG: 'rone/service/tests/tests_applicationfilerule_delete.py' indexed as test with language 'py'
10:41:19.456 INFO: 22 files indexed
10:41:19.457 INFO: 18 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
```

**EDIT 3. - Solution**
Problem was pylint report which didn't had proper exclusions.
So when importing Pylint/lint, Coverage and UnitTest reports. Check that those doesn't import any unwanted results. Lesson Learned. :D

Comment: Using `sonar.tests` should be the way to go, it shouldn't raise issues like "code smells" on test files. I suggest to update your post to give the full content of your sonar-project.properties and give the path of a "test" file on which an issue is raised but shouldn't be.

Comment: @Pierre-Yves I thought from documentation that using ```sonar.tests``` would be sufficient but still i get those. So i'm puzzled what i'm missing from configs.

Comment: Using `sonar.projectBaseDir` makes thinks more complex than usual. I suggest that you run `sonar-scanner -X` to get debug logs, and then give us the lines which look like `DEBUG: 'myproj/__init__.py' indexed with language 'py'`.

Comment: On which files do you get code smells or duplications which are "indexed as test"? Which code smell do you get?

Comment: i think i found the problem. It was pylint report as it had tests included. Configured pylint to exclude tests and no more code smells from test files.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. That would help the people who will hit the same problem in the future!